# Animate a group of svg element with Velocity.js

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, svg-animate, velocity.js

I am trying to animate a group of svg element which have previously been translated to a new position . I am using Velocity.js to animate the group to the center of viewport.
  However i am struggling to animate the group to the center of the viewport.

The attached [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KashifMKH/kd0s27vq/3/) and velocity function below shows that the group is animated from the top left to the right of the view port ,which is not what I want.

How can I animate the group from the new position to the center of the screen?

```
function Customize()
          { 
                  var bound=document.getElementById('parentsvg'); 
                  var width = (bound.width.baseVal.value);
                  var height = bound.height.baseVal.value;
                  var dx= (width/2);
                  var dy= (height/2);
                  var gro = document.getElementById('group');
                  var cl = gro.getBoundingClientRect();
                  var width = (cl.width / 2) ;
                  var height = (cl.height / 2);
                  var xx = dx - width;
                  var yy = dy - height;
                Velocity(gro,{translateX:xx,translateY:yy},{duration:5000},{queue:false});
}
```

Here is my Jsfiddle 
  http://jsfiddle.net/KashifMKH/kd0s27vq/3/

Comment: I'm guessing you may need to account for the viewBox scaling ? Maybe something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197118/how-do-i-get-the-width-of-a-scaled-svg-element-with-javascript will help.

Comment: @lan i need to move relative to the last transform .is there any method in velocity.js to perform this .